# How to find active li tab using WebDriver Java

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver

When i run my tests i want to determine if the right category (bn) is selected and active on the page. This is done by `<li class="active">`. In my test data i have all the products matched to every category so i know when the tab should be active, but i cant figure out how to assert this correct. Can anyone help me in the right direction? :)

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <h3><span>Hovedkategorier</span></h3>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="shortcuts">
        <li><a href=""><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 1</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="?tag=weekly1"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 2</span></span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="main">
        <li><a href="?bn=10000"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 3</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="?bn=10306"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 4</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="?bn=10723"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 5</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="?bn=10719"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 6</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="?bn=10190"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 7</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="?bn=10444"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 8</span></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="?bn=10431"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 9</span></span></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="?bn=10560"><span class="one"><span class="two">Text 10</span></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider selecting your element [by class name](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#by-class-name), like so:

```
List<WebElement> activeListElements = driver.findElements(By.className("active"));
```

Next, you should find the `<a>` inside the `<li class="active">`:

```
List<WebElement> activeLinks = activeListElements.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
```

After that, you could check its contents using `WebElement.getText()`:

```
String url = element.getAttribute("href");
assertThat(url, is("?bn=10000")); // for recent JUnit 4.x versions
assertEquals("?bn=10000", url); // for older versions of JUnit
```

Comment: Yep! But how to connect the active li to the category the href link after `<li class="active">` `assertEquals("?bn=10000", getTheBnFromActiveLiClass)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly, my understanding is you know `Text 6` or `href="?bn=10719"` should be the active tab. So you can find it using text or href, then check if its parent `<li>` tag actually has class `active`.

```
// using text is not applicable in your case, as they will be in different languages.
// WebElement tab = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[text()='Text 6']/.."));

int number = 10719;
WebElement liActive = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@href='?bn=" + number + "']/..")); // use '/..' to get <a>'s parent, which is the <li> 
String classNames = liActive.getAttribute("class");

// using whatever testing framework you prefer
// assert true that
// classNames.toLowerCase().contains("active")

// if you are sure that active will be the only class for li, you can check equality
// classNames.toLowerCase().Equals("active")
```

Comment: Aha! I don't know the Text 6 and don't want to know since the webpage is in 4 different languages. But i think i can modify this so i can use the a href attribute i stead of text()? I know the bn number in the link, so that is the easiest way for me.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try later on today and give you an update :)